# Blocking the Application class via runBlocking kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a confusion about how Dispatchers work in Kotlin

**Task** 
In my Application class I intend to access my database via Room, take out the user , take out his JWT accessToken and set it in another object that my retrofit Request inteceptor uses.

However I want all this code to be blocking , so that when the Application class has ran to its completion , the user has been extracted and set in the Inteceptor.

**Problem**
My application class runs to completion BEFORE the user has been picked from the database.

Session class is the one which accesses Room

This is how my session class looks

```
class Session(private val userRepository: UserRepository, private var requestHeaders: RequestHeaders) {

    var authenticationState: AuthenticationState = AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED
    var loggedUser: User? by Delegates.observable<User?>(null) { _, _, user ->
        if (user != null) {
            user.run {
                loggedRoles = roleCsv.split(",")
                loggedRoles?.run {
                    if (this[0] == "Employer") {
                        employer = toEmployer()
                    } else if (this[0] == "Employee") {
                        employee = toEmployee()
                    }
                }
                authenticationState = AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED
                requestHeaders.accessToken = accessToken
            }
        } else {
            loggedRoles = null
            employer = null
            employee = null
            authenticationState = AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED
            requestHeaders.accessToken = null
        }
    }
    var loggedRoles: List<String>? = null
    var employee: Employee? = null
    var employer: Employer? = null


    init {
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            loggedUser = userRepository.loggedInUser()
            Log.d("Session","User has been set")
        }

    }

//    var currentCity
//    var currentLanguage

}

enum class AuthenticationState {
    AUTHENTICATED,          // Initial state, the user needs to secretQuestion
    UNAUTHENTICATED,        // The user has authenticated successfully
    LOGGED_OUT,          // The user has logged out.
}
```

This is my Application class

```
class MohreApplication : Application()
{
    private val session:Session by inject()
    private val mohreDatabase:MohreDatabase by inject() // this is integral. Never remove this from here. This seeds the data on database creation
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MohreApplication)
            modules(listOf(
                platformModule,
                networkModule,
              ....
            ))
        }




        Log.d("Session","Launching application")


    }
```

My Koin module which creates the session

```
val platformModule = module {

//    single { Navigator(androidApplication()) }
    single { Session(get(),get()) }
    single { CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job()) }


}
```

In my Logcat first "Launching Application" prints out and THEN "User has been set"

Shouldn't it be reverse? . This is causing my application to launch without the Session having the user and my MainActivity complains.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is the purpose of a "phantom delay"?

Comment: Pawel I am updated my real problem

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib hey! this is too much implementation detail. try to boil it down to the most important part. try to create a minimal example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by inject()` is using kotlin lazy initialization. Only when `session.loggedUser` is queried will the `init` block be fired.

In your case, when you call `session.loggedUser` in the MainActivity, the `init` block will fire and block the calling thread.

What you can do is.

```
import org.koin.android.ext.android.get

class MohreApplication : Application()
{
    private lateinit var session: Session
    private lateinit var mohreDatabase: MohreDatabase // this is integral. Never remove this from here. This seeds the data on database creation
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MohreApplication)
            modules(listOf(
                platformModule,
                networkModule,
              ....
            ))
        }

        session = get()
        mohreDatabase = get()

        Log.d("Session","Launching application")


    }
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Ill try to create my Session class away from Koin and report back the results

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib I've updated my answer to fix your problem.